# How to find the directories in which the executable files are located, display them and so that they do not repeat? Linux

Tags: linux

i used this:

```
list=$(find "$1" -type f -executable)
echo "list"
```

But dont know how to  display exactly the previous directory of executable files

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -executable -print | sort -u | uniq
```

This way you can find it and avoid repeating the same string with the command uniq.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to display the previous directory when you find it? For example I found the file in  /home/user/123.exe   And you need to output  /home/user

Comment: find . -type f -executable -print | sort -u | uniq  | rev | cut -d "/" -f 2-3 | rev

can you try this command